# Passing Java threads' parameters as local ones

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have an array in Java:

```
  int[] arr = {1,5,-1,4,7,10};
  ProcessingThread pt1 = new ProcessingThread(arr[0]);
  Thread t1 = new Thread(pt1)
  ProcessingThread pt2 = new ProcessingThread(arr[1]);
  Thread t2 = new Thread(pt2)
  ..
  t1.start()
  t2.start()
  ..
```

and I want each thread to take one element from this array and do some calculations.

How can I make sure that each of the elements (arr[1], arr[2], etc) is a local one (i.e., not shared with other threads or in other words thread-safe) ?

Comment: Well you're passing an `int` to the `ProcessingThread` constructor... at that point, the `ProcessingThread` itself won't be referring to the array at all.

Comment: it is already thread safe as you are injecting different number to different threads and you are not passing integer array itself to threads?

Comment: I would take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html).

Comment: Each Thread will make its own copy from the passed parameters, so it'll not reflect to the `arr` object.

Comment: yeah but in the  <Processing Thread> class the integer variable is defined as follows:
class ProcessingThread implements Runnable
{
 private int num;
public ProcessingThread(int num)
{
this.num = num
} 
}

and thus this.num becomes global and at any time a thread X changes its value, the other threads will change their values too

I want this.num to be treated as a local variable where each thread is sure that there will be no one that could change its own value ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do; if your intent is thread-safe parallel processing of elements in a list, [queues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) are one option (blocking or non-blocking), depending on your needs. Boris' suggestion using Streams is also good.

Comment: In fact I want each thread to take a number from the array arr and to continue some calculations .... so I don't want any thread to see the value of the other one ... (independant elements) .... and whenever anyone of them changes the value of its element, I don't want it to be visible to other threads.
I hope that it is clearer now ?

Comment: Why would a thread see and modify a private variable of another thread?

Comment: for example in the following link http://www.journaldev.com/1061/java-synchronization-and-thread-safety-tutorial-with-examples
We can see that when any thread t1 or t2 modifies tp, both of them can see the modification .. and I don't want this to happen ?

Comment: @HadoopUser in the posted example, each thread uses the same ProcessingThread instance as its runnable. That's why they both read and modify the same state. In your above code, each thread uses a separate instance of ProcessingThread, so that won't happen: each instance has its own, private, int variable.

Comment: Ah ok I see, and what if I also want all of them to put some answers in a shared memory (i.e. define a new shared array where they can put some answers at some moment) ? how can I pass this global array as a parameter ?

Comment: You really, really, *really* want to read Java Concurrency in Practice before writing a single line of multithreaded code. With the knowledge you have at the moment there's just no way that you could write a working concurrent application even with all the help SO could give.